# Como deletar todos os arquivos e subpastas de um diretório?

Tags: php, html, sistema-de-arquivos

Tenho um site de armazenamento de arquivos, e com um tempo ele move arquivos inativos para uma pasta: `www.site.com/files/_deleted/`, quando ele move os arquivos ele cria uma subpasta para cada um deles... Tem como eu executar um código *PHP* pra apagar todo conteúdo dessa pasta, **mas não apagar ela em si?**

Apagar pelo *FTP* demora muito.... Pelo *PHP* eu poderia ate mesmo criar um cron para executar em um determinado tempo.

**Alguém pode me ajudar ?**

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3352564/1452488) te ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode listar todos arquivos dentro deste diretório e apagá-los dessa forma:

```
$arquivos = scandir(www.site.com/files/_deleted/);

foreach ($arquivos as $arquivo){

    // Verifica se é uma subpasta e apaga os arquivos dentro
    foreach (scandir($arquivo) as $item) {
        unlink($item);
    }

    // Se não for uma pasta, exclui o arquivo
    if (!is_dir($arquivo)) {
        unlink($arquivo);
    }

    // Por fim, apaga a pasta
    rmdir($arquivo);
}
```

De forma mais simplificada, você pode usar comandos do SO pra apagar a pasta, mas essa solução só funciona em LINUX (eu acho)

```
$dir = 'www.site.com/files/_deleted/*';
// chama o comando do SO
system('rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir), $retorno);
// esse comando linux retorna 0 quando sucesso
if( $retorno == 0) echo "Excluido com sucesso";
```

Comment: No caso em www.site.com/files/_deleted/ Posso colocar só /files/_deleted/ por ele ta hospedado no mesmo server...

Comment: Boa. Testa aí e qualquer dúvida me fala :)

Comment: Não funcionou.... da erro 500

Comment: Porem a forma simplificada funcionou...mas também apaga a pasta.. eu queria que apagasse somente o que tem dentro dela...

Comment: Hmm, para não apagar a própria pasta, coloque um * no final do caminho. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!